# sed command does not execute properly on gitlab runner

Tags: linux, shell, sed, gitlab, gnu

I have a script which needs to run npm run test and capture test coverage coverage value
[image] so here I am trying to capture the value 36.95

and output it in gitlab script which  I am planning to add as a gitlab job. It seems that the runner is gnu. If I execute the below script on my local it works fine as in returns 36.95.
However if I run it on gitlab it returns the value of the `npm run test` . How can I make it compattible with the runner I am using.

```
RES=$(npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false)
TOTAL=$(sed -E 's/^.* All files \| ([^ ]+) \| .*$/\1/' <<< $RES)
echo "Current test coverage is : " $TOTAL
```

I think here-string(<<<) is not compatible with the runner which is why it works on my local machine but not on gitlab maybe there is some issue with my script too.
Gitlab pipleline config

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: node:16.13.1
  before_script:
    - npm i
    - npx node -v
    - npx npm -v
  script:
    - echo "running test coverage"
    - bash test.sh
```

`test.sh` contains the script mentioned at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pipe directly to `sed`

```
total=$(npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false | sed -En '/All files/s/^[^|]*\| +([[:digit:].]+).*$/\1/p')
echo "Current test coverage is :  $total"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [the alternative to `<<<`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80372/7490)

```
TOTAL=$(echo "${RES}"|grep "All files"|sed -E 's/^.* All files \| ([^ ]+) \| .*$/\1/')
```

Meaning you isolate the line you want to `sed`.